# Send e-mail to current user with Sharepoint designer 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I want to send an e-mail to the current user after updating a list item for error handling purposes.
How can I capture data needed to tell the workflow who to e-mail?
All the e-mail addresses seem to be static.
I am using SP10 with SharePoint Designer 2010 and Exchange (Outlook) e-mails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for "Workflow Lookup for a User..".

Just select "Workflow Lookup for a User.." > current item > modified by. This would send the email to the one who modified the item. Or you could just chose any other column, like created by. Or if you are using any custom People columns.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I also just found this on my own.  I tend to forget that this runs after the edit is complete, not during the editing process.  That makes a difference in the state of data and what can or cannot be done with Designer.

Comment: Been working to much with event receivers? :)

Comment: I Wish!! @user19952. Actually, my thought process is geared toward event receivers because of the nature of other IT items I am involved in, but we aren't allowed the power of an event receiver at this point.  So I have to step back and rethink how Workflows function and therefore what my capabilities and limitations are.

Comment: Haha!  I tried with "Return field as: Email" and it didn't work - then I found this post and tried "Return field as: Display Name" and it worked!  Go figure!